# Extract certain elements from a list

Tags: python, join

I have no clue about Python and started to use it on some files. I managed to find out how to do all the things that I need, except for 2 things.

**1st**

```
>>>line = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
>>>#prints all elements of line as expected
>>>print string.join(line)
0 1 2 3 4 5 6

>>>#prints the first two elements as expected
>>>print string.join(line[0:2])
0 1

>>>#expected to print the first, second, fourth and sixth element;
>>>#Raises an exception instead
>>>print string.join(line[0:2:4:6])
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I want this to work similar to `awk '{ print $1 $2 $5 $7 }'`. How can I accomplish this?

**2nd**

how can I delete the last character of the line? There is an additional `'` that I don't need.

Comment: I've answered as best as I can, given it looks like your code is wrong (what's `line`), and I'm not entirely clear what output you want. If you clarify those two things I might be able to be more helpful!

Answer (score 5):

Provided the join here is just to have a nice string to print or store as result (with a coma as separator, in the OP example it would have been whatever was in string).

```
line = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']

print ','.join (line[0:2])
```

A,B

```
print ','.join (line[i] for i in [0,1,2,4,5,6])
```

A,B,C,E,F,G

What you are doing in both cases is extracting a sublist from the initial list. The first one use a slice, the second one use a list comprehension. As others said you could also have accessed to elements one by one, the above syntaxes are merely shorthands for:

```
print ','.join ([line[0], line[1]])
```

A,B

```
print ','.join ([line[0], line[1], line[2], line[4], line[5], line[6]])
```

A,B,C,E,F,G

I believe some short tutorial on list slices could be helpfull:

- `l[x:y]` is a 'slice' of list l. It will get all elements between position x (included) and position y (excluded). Positions starts at 0. If y is out of list or missing, it will include all list until the end. If you use negative numbers you count from the end of the list. You can also use a third parameter like in `l[x:y:step]` if you want to 'jump over' some items (not take them in the slice) with a regular interval.

Some examples:

```
l = range(1, 100) # create a list of 99 integers from 1 to 99
l[:]    # resulting slice is a copy of the list
l[0:]   # another way to get a copy of the list
l[0:99] # as we know the number of items, we could also do that
l[0:0]  # a new empty list (remember y is excluded]
l[0:1]  # a new list that contains only the first item of the old list
l[0:2]  # a new list that contains only the first two items of the old list
l[0:-1] # a new list that contains all the items of the old list, except the last
l[0:len(l)-1] # same as above but less clear 
l[0:-2] # a new list that contains all the items of the old list, except the last two
l[0:len(l)-2] # same as above but less clear
l[1:-1] # a new list with first and last item of the original list removed
l[-2:] # a list that contains the last two items of the original list
l[0::2] # odd numbers
l[1::2] # even numbers
l[2::3] # multiples of 3
```

If rules to get items are more complex, you'll use a [list comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) instead of a slice, but it's another subjet. That's what I use in my second join example.

Comment: this does not work.
it says:
  print ' '.join (line[0], line[1], line[4], line[6])
TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (4 given)

Comment: @tiger: oups, forgot square brackets around list. Thanks for spoting the problem. It's corrected.

Comment: yes :-) it works also!
now I have the %s also kicked out, like mentioned before.

Comment: +1 for the list comprehension - much more elegant than my `map` solution!

Comment: @tiger, This answer is very thorough and if you like it you should select it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use `join` for that. If you just want to print some bits of a list, then specify the ones you want directly:

```
print '%s %s %s %s' % (line[0], line[1], line[4], line[6])
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second item in the tuple be `line[1]` instead? (Assuming he wants the 2nd element in the list)

Comment: Hi Thanks, that helps so far! but I did a split before and thought to use a join after that.
Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: @tiger - You could use `join`, but I reckon that makes your code more complicated not less.

Comment: `%` is on the track to deprecation and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Yes thank you for the hint.
The line has several cells or fields and if I like to print out only some of them I thought I need to split them.
I seemd logic to me to join them after that :-)
Script has 19 codelines now so it is not realy complicated I think!
I just need to add someting to write the outcome in a file and than I'm done.
But it is the first thing in python so I'm happy that it works!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `line` variable should contain a line of cells, separated by commas...

You can use `map` for that:

```
line = "1,2,3,4,5,6"
cells = line.split(",")
indices=[0,1,4,6]
selected_elements = map( lambda i: cells[i], indices )
print ",".join(selected_elements)
```

The `map` function will do the on-the-fly function for each of the indices in the list argument.  (Reorder to your liking)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following using list comprehension :

```
indices = [0,1,4,6]
Ipadd = string.join([line[i] for i in xrange(len(line)) if i in indices])
```

Note : You could also use :

```
Ipadd = string.join([line[i] for i in indices])
```

but you will need a sorted list of indices without repetition of course.

Comment: or sort and duplicate removal can be done by python `[line[i] for i in sorted(set(indices))]`

Comment: @kriss Indeed, it's maybe the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the second question:

If your string is contained in `myLine`, just do:

```
myLline = myLine[:-1]
```

to remove the last character.

Or you could also use [`rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
myLine = myLine.rstrip("'")
```

Comment: Thank you [:-1] steals the las cell, I had that before.
I have like 10 to 13 cells at the end so if I have 10 cells the -1 prints out nothing.
Location = Location.rstrip("'") did it!

Answer (score 1):

```
l = []
l.extend(line[0:2])
l.append(line[5]) # fourth field
l.append(line[7]) # sixth field
string.join(l)
```

Alternatively

```
"{l[0]} {l[1]} {l[4]} {l[5]}".format(l=line)
```

Please [see PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) and stop using the `%` operator for string formatting.

Comment: Thanks @xtofl, I was just following the OP's example.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> token = ':'
>>> s = '1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10'
>>> sp = s.split(token)
>>> token.join(filter(bool, map(lambda i: i in [0,2,4,6] and sp[i] or False, range(len(sp)))))
'1:3:5:7'
```